A man standing in an elevator at the third floor of a building. What is the primary factor that determines the man's kinetic energy?
Misconception in Elevator Kinetic Energy Question
I recently encountered the following question in a physics entry test exam:
Question: A man standing in an elevator at the third floor of a building. What is the primary factor that determines the man's kinetic energy?
a. His height above the ground 
b. his mass
C. elevator's speed
d. elevator's direction of movement
How here we can consider Option B
The exam marked option B (his mass) as correct, but I'm not convinced this is accurate. Can someone explain the reasoning behind this answer and address the issues with the other options?
My Thoughts
Kinetic energy is defined as KE = (1/2)mv², where m is mass and v is velocity.
In this scenario, the man is described as "standing" in the elevator, which implies he's not moving relative to the elevator.
The elevator's movement (if any) isn't specified in the question.
Given these points, I believe there are issues with all the answer choices:
a. Height above ground relates to potential energy, not kinetic energy.
b. Mass is a factor in kinetic energy, but it's not sufficient on its own to determine KE.
c. The elevator's speed would be crucial if it were moving, but it's not specified.
d. The direction of movement doesn't directly affect the magnitude of kinetic energy.
Is there a flaw in my reasoning, or is this question problematic? How should this concept be correctly addressed in a physics exam?

This type of question does more harm than good to the student subjected to it.

First of all, kinetic energy (KE) is reference frame dependent. In the frame of the elevator, as long as the man moves with the elevator, the man's KE will always be zero.
That said, in any other inertial frame KE varies as the square of the speed of the man and linearly with mass. So it would seem B is not correct. Since it is the magnitude of the velocity (speed) and not direction of velocity that is relevant to KE, (d) seems irrelevant. Finally (a) is applicable to potential not kinetic energy.
So it seems (c) is correct, as long as the man and elevator move together.
Hope this helps.

The question is a bit misleading so let's go straight to it.

If the elevator's speed is $v = 0$, then the mass has no effect whatsoever and $v$ is the "primary factor" causing $K_E = 0$
If the elevator's speed is $v \neq 0$, then it is open to interpretation. One could argue by considering typical ranges of values for $v$ and $m$, or the fact that $v^2$ is squared in the formula for $K_E$.

Anyway, there is no explicit mention of the elevator's movement, but yet an elevator is mentioned. So the question is at least misleading (by trying to see if you confuse the potential and kinetic energies), and the best would be to directly ask the author what (s)he had in mind.
